# Three Apple devices in the same location: Two can connect to a Wi-Fi but iPhone 6 cannot

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

I am currently having problems with 3 Apple wifi-capable devices in the same location - in a garage outside a main building.

All three devices can connect to the wifi network with no issues within the main building.

Once moved to a garage, the Mid 2014 MacBook Pro and new iPad 2 are still able to connect to the wifi hotspot and they both indicate strong signal strength: MacBook Pro shows full 5 bars and the iPad shows 2 (out of 3) bars.

The iPhone 6 simply cannot connect to the same Wi-Fi hotspot at all. I have tried turning on and off wifi and airplane mode. They do not have any effect.

Does this indicate a hardware problem?
What can I do to make iPhone connect to the Wi-Fi?

Comment: What is the model of the wifi router?  I suspect it has 2.4 and 5 ghz wireless and the iphone is trying to connect only to the 5ghz (which doesn't have the same range as 2.4ghz but would be much faster when in range.)

Comment: Does your iPhone connect to other wireless networks?

Comment: The wifi router is an Airport Extreme (last generation)

Comment: At the end I took the cover of the iphone off and it can connect again, and remain so even after putting the cover back on. I think it will be difficult to reproduce this issue and incline to close this question. What do you think?